# Laravel Eloquent get relationship with keyBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `Product` model with a `hasMany` relationship

```
public function pricing()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPrice', 'prod_id', 'id');
    }
```

I then get the relationship

```
Product::with('pricing')->all();
```

How can I retrieve the `pricing` relationship with the `id` as the key. I know I can do it on a `Collection` with `keyBy('id)` but it doesn't work on a query.

I want to acheive the same results as below but I want to get it from the `Product` relationship.

```
ProductPrice::keyBy('id')
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to create your own relationship:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Classes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class HasManyKeyBy extends HasMany
{
    private $keyBy;

    public function __construct($keyBy, Builder $query, Model $parent, string $foreignKey, string $localKey)
    {
        $this->keyBy = $keyBy;
        parent::__construct($query, $parent, $foreignKey, $localKey);
    }

    public function getResults()
    {
        return parent::getResults()->keyBy($this->keyBy);
    }

    protected function getRelationValue(array $dictionary, $key, $type)
    {
        return parent::getRelationValue($dictionary, $key, $type)->keyBy($this->keyBy);
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I also recommend you to create a trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

trait HasManyKeyBy
{
    /**
     * @param $keyBy
     * @param $related
     * @param null $foreignKey
     * @param null $localKey
     * @return HasMany
     */
    protected function hasManyKeyBy($keyBy, $related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    {
        // copied from \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships::hasMany

        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new \App\Helpers\Classes\HasManyKeyBy($keyBy, $instance->newQuery(),
            $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
    }
}
```

Now, you can include this trait into your model, and use `$this->hasManyKeyBy` protected method:

```
[...]
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasManyKeyBy;

    public function pricing()
    {
        return $this->hasManyKeyBy('id', ProductPrice::class, 'prod_id', 'id');
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: This answer is seriously underrated

Answer (score 6):

A quick workaround is to replace the current relation in you array using setRelation method. In your case:

```
$product = Product::with('pricing')->all();
$product->setRelation('pricing', $product->pricing->keyBy('id'));
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could also do is define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```
/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getPricingByIdAttribute() : Collection
{
    return $this->pricing->keyBy('id');
}
```

Then on each product returned in the Collection you can get the pricing by the id using:

```
$pricing = $product->pricing_by_id;
```

Make sure to still eager load the pricing if necessary:

```
$products = Product::query()->with('pricing')->get();
```

Also, when returning the Products in e.g. an API using json you could use [appending to json](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json):

```
$products->each->append('pricing_by_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't 'keyBy' an existing relationship.

However, you can create a 'fake' attribute that you return which can be keyed. So instead:

```
$products = Product::with('pricing') -> all();
$products -> keyedPricing = $products -> pricing -> keyBy('id');
$products -> addVisible('keyedPricing');
```