# Laravel Eloquent relationship keyBy()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

i want to modify the result set of relationship in the following way

I have this array

```
    array:11 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "user_id" => 1
      "name" => "Test Case"
      "created_at" => "2017-08-25 17:12:26"
      "updated_at" => "2017-08-29 11:59:46"
      "hashid" => "5LOkAdWNDqgVomK"
      "user" => array:8 [▶]
      "order" => array:8 [▶]
      "classification" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:9 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "case_id" => 1
          "method" => "facial_map_manual"
          "strong" => 2.0
          "dynamic" => 30.0
          "delicate" => 50.0
          "calm" => 18.0
          "created_at" => "2017-08-31 11:00:00"
          "updated_at" => "2017-08-31 11:00:00"
        ]
        1 => array:9 [▼
          "id" => 2
          "case_id" => 1
          "method" => "interview"
          "strong" => 20.0
          "dynamic" => 25.0
          "delicate" => 30.0
          "calm" => 25.0
          "created_at" => "2017-08-31 11:00:00"
          "updated_at" => "2017-08-31 11:00:00"
        ]
      ]
      "classification_data" => array:3 [▼
        0 => array:6 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "case_id" => 1
          "type" => "facial_points"
          "data" => null
          "created_at" => "2017-08-31 11:00:00"
          "updated_at" => "2017-08-31 11:00:00"
        ]
        1 => array:6 [▼
          "id" => 2
          "case_id" => 1
          "type" => "interview"
          "data" => array:4 [▶]
          "created_at" => "2017-08-31 12:00:00"
          "updated_at" => "2017-08-31 11:00:00"
        ]
        2 => array:6 [▶]
      ]
      "teeth_configuration" => array:6 [▶]
    ]
```

I want to map **classification** and **classification_data** by column key ( type OR method ) which are loaded relationships. 
This is the query:

```
 $case = RCase::with(['user','order','classification','classificationData','teethConfiguration'])->where('id',$id)
                    ->first();
```

This is what i tried so far

```
$case->classificationData =  $case->classificationData->keyBy('type')->toArray();
```

With the first method they are ordered by type but the old **classification_data** stays there even if try to

```
 unlink($case->classification_data)
```

This is not the big problem... I can do this also with **classification** but the data stays the same.

**Is there any method with which i can do keyBy() straight in the loaded relation model ?** Thanks in advance

```
PHP Version: 7.1
Laravel Version: 5.4.38
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288091/1478566).

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the relation with this code:

```
$case->setRelation("classification_data",$case->classificationData->keyBy('type'));
```

To replace the relation you must provide the same relation name or laravel will create another one.

When you do:

```
$case->classificationData = something
```

You are actually adding a new attribute to the model object.